# Expo App not showing popup for Location Permission

Tags: android, react-native, expo

In my expo app I want to get a user's location I am trying the same code as on the official website of Expo for getting User's location.
But expo app is not showing popup for location permission, please see the code below,

```
componentWillMount() {
this._getLocationAsync();
}

_getLocationAsync = async () => {
let { status } = await Permissions.askAsync(Permissions.CAMERA);
if (status !== 'granted') {
  this.setState({
    errorMessage: 'Permission to access location was denied',
  });
}

// let location = await Location.getCurrentPositionAsync({});
// this.setState({ location });
};
```

On the other hand if I replace Permissions.LOCATION with Permissions.CAMERA the app shows popup for permission.

Please help I am unable to solve this issue I am using android device

Answer (score 1):

First componentWillMount is deprecated. Try it with componentDidMount

Second you may already gave location permission to app. Check settings on the phone if permission is already provided. If yes, change it on the settings and try again.

```
componentDidMount() {
this._getLocationAsync();
}

_getLocationAsync = async () => {
let { status } = await Permissions.askAsync(Permissions.CAMERA);
if (status !== 'granted') {
  this.setState({
    errorMessage: 'Permission to access location was denied',
  });
}

// let location = await Location.getCurrentPositionAsync({});
// this.setState({ location });
};
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer @sinan,I tried  _componentDidMount_ but the problem was in my mobile when  I ran the app in my friends mobile It asked for location permission.

Comment: Yeah as I said in the post, in your phone you may already gave location permission to your app and permission isn't given in your friend's phone. Therefore the app is asking for permission in your friend's phone and not in yours. As a result I suggest you check settings of your phone once again to make sure location permission is not provided for the app.